# Google Cloud Resource created with user that is not in IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

Situation:

- I have a GCP project (`owner`) that is under a organization I do not have access to, so I see it in `No Organization`
- a user (`xyz@domain.com`) has created a subscription for an existing pubsub topic, I see that under activity and the audit logs
- this user is not visible for me in IAM (e.g. as `editor`, or with some pubsub specific role)
- neither can I see this user in any pub/sub related topic/subscription, with a role, specifically not in the topic he created the subscription in

Summary:

- `xyz@domain.com` created a subs.
- I don't know where he got the role from (inherited?)

Question:

1. Is it possible that this person has e.g. `editor` on the organization (or some folder above the project) but I don't see that role in my IAM section of the project?
2. If not, where could the role be inherited from?

Comment: Did you see any add/remove member around the pubsub topic creation?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no, I did not see any activity in this regard in the project's audit logs, but will check again

Comment: Could you please explain "...project ... is under No Organization (I do not have access to the parent org)"? This sounds a bit contradictory. Does an Organisation node actually exist in the object hierarchy, or not (for instance projects are created without Organization and Folders)?

Comment: @mebius99: see here (in the box): https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization Quote: (referring to "No Organization") Projects for which the user has access to, but are under an Organization to which the user does not have access.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. So the first point in the Situation description should be understood as "... a project is actually **under an Organization**, but I do not have access to that parent Org" and can't view it.

Comment: @mebius99 thanks, edited the post to made it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating a Subscribtion**

To subscribe to a Pub/Sub topic a user should be able to create a Subscription object. To do that, a permission **pubsub.subscriptions.create** on a Topic is needed. It could be assigned explicitly onto a Topic or inherited from the parent levels (Project, Folder, Org) via:

- a Custom Role inherited from the Project level or above;
- a Predefined Role **pubsub.editor** or **pubsub.admin** assigned at the Pub/Sub Topic level or inherited from a parent level;
- a Primitive Role **Editor** or **Owner** inherited from the Project or Service Resource level or above; for example, the **Compute Engine default service account** freshly created VM Instances are working on behalf of has an **Editor** Role on the Project it is part of.

**Viewing role assignments**

To trace where effective rights are inherited from, one would need at list the following Permssions:

- resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy
- resourcemanager.folders.getIamPolicy
- resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy

IAM Predefined Roles that contain that permissions are:

- resourcemanager.organizationAdmin
- iam.securityAdmin
- iam.securityReviewer

IAM Predefined Roles that can trace up to the Folder level are:

- resourcemanager.folderAdmin
- resourcemanager.folderEditor
- resourcemanager.folderIamAdmin

IAM Primitive Roles:

- Viewer
- Editor
- Owner

To obtain the comprehensive view of resulting permissions you should be granted the Roles listed above assigned as high as possible in the IAM hierarchy (ideally at the Org level) to get enough administrative scope for investigation.

You can't see bindings that are located outside of the administrative scope you've got. Therefore you can't see the level where permissions are inherited from as well as security subject the permissions are granted for.

**Back to the questions**

1. Is it possible that this person has e.g. editor on the organization (or some folder above the project) but I don't see that role in my IAM section of the project?

   - Yes
2. If not, where could the role be inherited from?

   - An Org level and all Folder levels (those could be nested) above your Project.

**Vendor documentation**

[IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#iam-roles)

[Cloud Pub/Sub | Access Control | Roles](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles)

[Support level for permissions in custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support)

Comment: thanks, I think this one paragraph is the core of my question: `You can't see bindings that are located outside of the administrative scope you've got. Therefore you can't see the level where permissions are inherited from as well as security subject the permissions are granted for.` Thanks. Not sure if I agree with "The Roles listed above should be assigned as high as possible" - it is valid for investigation but violates the principle of least privilege, in all other cases. Thanks, will accept!

Comment: That is exactly what I mean: permission scope for investigation purposes. Thanks for pointing that. The answer is refined.